# Faster execution within a For Next loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, for-loop

I'm looking to make this piece of code faster at runtime and maybe, even, better built.
If you have an idea, I'm interested. Thank you. Claude.

```
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()

For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
     TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(ListBox2.Items(i))
Next
```

ListBox2 contains only sorted unique strings, which allows me to not write in the TextBox1 text box, a duplicate string.

Comment: How did these *unique strings* end up inside a ListBox? Do you have a collection of strings stored somewhere else? Do you need the ListBox at all? When is this code run? Why do you have `TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()` there? Are you resetting the collection when *something happens*? On what condition? How often? Why don't you set the entire collection of string as the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` all at once (e.g., `TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = [Some list of strings]`)?

Comment: 1) How did these unique strings end up inside a ListBox? From a Treeview. 
2) Do you have a collection of strings stored somewhere else? In the Treeview cited above. 
3) Do you need the ListBox at all? When is this code run? Yes, I really need it.
4) When is this code run? When I create a new blank form to fill in my text boxes.
5) Why do you have TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear() there? In order to reset the list.
6) Are you resetting the collection when something happens? No.
7) On what condition? Only when I create a new form.
8) How often? Right now a hundred times a day.

Comment: 9) Why don't you set the entire collection of string as the AutoCompleteCustomSource all at once (e.g., TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = [Some list of strings])? Good, because I didn't think about it.

Comment: *From a Treeview*: same question. So, what is the approx. number of strings you're dealing with? + You got them somewhere, what is the source? -- Now, these strings are used in a TreeView, a ListBox and another collection used for the AutoComplete feature. Anywhere else? Another collection filled by the data source? -- If you have it, use it. -- I could argue that these *strings* are used in too many places, but I won't do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind *AutoCompleteCustomSource* to *AutoCompleteStringCollection*:

```
    Dim strArr As String() = ListBox2.Items.OfType(Of String)().ToArray()
    Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    MySource.AddRange(strArr)
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
```

Comment: Thank you Xingyu Zhao. Excellent!

Answer (score -2):

you can try this:

```
for each i to listbox.items.count -1
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(ListBox2.Items(i))
next
end for
```

the form goes catch i in real time and add list intem -1 then go to other line and terminate end